# isotope filtering only detecting first item as visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I'm using an `isinviewport` script throughout my site to detect when something is visible in the viewport. However when trying to use it with Isotope filtering it's only detecting the first item on first load, then as I scroll the item right next to it then gets the class applied to it.

I'm trying to get a class of `o-image-reveal` added to the first two items, which are visible in the viewport, on first load. I can't add these classes manually on the actual site.

Here is my code below:

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$('.js-image-reveal').each(function(i, el) {
  if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
    $(this).addClass('o-image-reveal');
  }
})

var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded(function() {
  $grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.portfolio__item'
  });
});

var filters = {};

$('.filters').on('click', '.filter__item', function(event) {
  var $button = $(event.currentTarget);
  var $buttonGroup = $button.parents('.button-group');
  var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
  filters[filterGroup] = $button.attr('data-filter');
  var filterValue = concatValues(filters);
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: filterValue
  });
});

$('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on('click', '.filter__item', function(event) {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    var $button = $(event.currentTarget);
    $button.addClass('is-checked');
  });
});

function concatValues(obj) {
  var value = '';
  for (var prop in obj) {
    value += obj[prop];
  }
  return value;
}
```

```css
.col-md-6 {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.col-md-12 {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.portfolio__item {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.filter__item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.o-image-reveal {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@5.0.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.6/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="work">
    <div class="filter__item is-checked" data-filter="">All work</div>
    <div class="filter__item" data-filter=".filter-one">Filter 1</div>
    <div class="filter__item" data-filter=".filter-two">Filter 2</div>
    <div class="filter__item" data-filter=".filter-three">Filter 3</div>
    <div class="filter__item" data-filter=".filter-four">Filter 4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <a href="#" class="portfolio__item col-md-6 filter-one">
    <img class="js-image-reveal" src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/600" /> Title Here
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="portfolio__item col-md-6 filter-two">
    <img class="js-image-reveal" src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/600" /> Title Here
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="portfolio__item col-md-12 filter-three">
    <img class="js-image-reveal" src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/600" /> Title Here
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="portfolio__item col-md-12 filter-four">
    <img class="js-image-reveal" src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/600" /> Title Here
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="portfolio__item col-md-6 filter-one">
    <img class="js-image-reveal" src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/600" /> Title Here
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="portfolio__item col-md-6 filter-two">
    <img class="js-image-reveal" src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/600" /> Title Here
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8vt216x/).

Comment: In your fiddle, no matter how wide I make the result window, it appears to add the class to _all six_ images every time.

Comment: And it gives me an error, `$('.grid').imagesLoaded` is not a function.

Comment: Logging `elementTop` in your isInViewport function gives me six times the same value, so presumably this executes before the images have even loaded. Have you tried putting that _into_ the `$('.grid').imagesLoaded` callback?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your help. I will update the jsfiddle and code to work with imagesloaded. How would i add the isinviewport script within the .imagesloaded?

Comment: Just put the `$('.js-image-reveal').each(...)` in there?